# SQL update query with multiple subqueries from one table with conditions from the original table

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery, sql-server-2019

I have the following query to get the latest GPS record for multiple devices from my `Records` table:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE
(DeviceID int, RecordID int, DeviceTime datetime, Own bit, New bit, ...);

--insert a few device IDs into @Result and set New = 0 and Own to 0 or 1
--then:
UPDATE @Result
SET New = 1,
RecordID = (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM Records WHERE Records.Device_ID = [@Result].DeviceID ORDER BY Records.DeviceTime DESC),
GPSTime = (SELECT TOP(1) DeviceTime FROM Records WHERE Records.Device_ID = [@Result].DeviceID ORDER BY Records.DeviceTime DESC)
WHERE Own = 1;
```

Is there any way to select `ID` and `DeviceTime` from `Records` with one subquery or in general optimize this query?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please write your output with an example

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase this an update join, using a CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Device_ID
                                 ORDER BY DeviceTime DESC) rn
    FROM Records
)

UPDATE a
SET New = 1,
    RecordID = b.ID,
    GPSTime = b.DeviceTime
FROM @Result a
INNER JOIN cte b
    ON b.Device_ID = a.DeviceID
WHERE a.Own = 1 AND b.rn = 1;
```

Comment: This works but `cte` uses all of `Records` table without filtering for devices (it includes records of devices that aren't in `@Result`) so it takes significantly longer.

Comment: Adding an index on `(Device_ID, DeviceTime)` might speed up my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution:

```
UPDATE @Result
SET New = 1, RecordID = R.ID, GPSTime = R.DeviceTime
FROM @Result
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP(1) ID, DeviceTime FROM Records WHERE Records.Device_ID = [@Result].DeviceID ORDER BY Records.DeviceTime DESC) AS R
WHERE Own = 1;
```